# Locate unique line among other repeated lines using python

Tags: python, file, repeat

I am having a file with basically few lines but repeated multiple times. I am trying to just take one line from the repeated stack and write it in different file. And trying to do for all the unique kind of lines.
My `file` is kind of following:

```
F Fluorin B 91
F Fluorin B 91
F Fluorin B 91
F Fluorin B 91  
I Iodin  C 22
I Iodin  C 22   
Cl chlorine D 21
Cl chlorine D 21
Cl chlorine D 21
Cl chlorine D 21
Cl chlorine D 21
Cl chlorine D 21
```

and Desired output is:

```
F Fluorin B 91 
I Iodin  C 22
Cl chlorine D 21
```

My code was:

```
seen = set()
uniqueEntry = []
for line in inp:
        if line not in seen:
            uniqueEntry = line.split('[]')
            seen.add(line)
```

But I am not getting desired result.
Any ideas are welcome.
thank you.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: I answered because I'm too tired to do my actual job at the moment, but in the future if you want good answers and to avoid downvotes, be sure to include the result you're getting and how it's different from what you want.

Comment: @thumbtackthief thank you for kind opinion...i'll surely keep in mind.

Comment: No worries @abhisek!  Also, be sure to comment on any answer below if you have any questions--we're all here to learn!

Comment: And don't forget to accept an answer once you've found one you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [12]: s = """F Fluorin B 91
   ....: F Fluorin B 91
   ....: F Fluorin B 91
   ....: F Fluorin B 91  
   ....: I Iodin  C 22
   ....: I Iodin  C 22   
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21
   ....: Cl chlorine D 21"""
In [13]: a = [v.strip() for v in s.split('\n')]
In [14]: from itertools import groupby
In [15]: zip(*groupby(a))[0]
Out[15]: ('F Fluorin B 91', 'I Iodin  C 22', 'Cl chlorine D 21')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some trailing white space at the end of some of your lines which is making things non-unique.
`strip()` will take care of that.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

a = set(lines)
print a
```

Comment: You don't need to create an intermediate list, just use `set` with a generator expression: `a = set(line.strip() for line in f)`

Comment: Definitely true--I figured mine might be a little clearer for someone learning, but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=open("file.txt")
f=open("fil2.txt", "w")
result=[]
for line in x:
    if line not in result:
        result.append(line)
for line in result:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
x.close()
```

Although this writes the last result twice, because the last result doesn't have \n in the end of it, this is easily bypassed by creating a new line in the text file after the last entry.